# Передача объекта по ссылке в другой процесс

Tags: c#, ipc

Существует ли какой-нибудь механизм передачи объектов именно по ссылке из одного процесса в другой? Чтобы несколько программ могли взаимодействовать с одним и тем же объектом.

Нагуглил про [MarshalByRefObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.marshalbyrefobject(v=vs.110).aspx), но пока не понял позволяет ли этот класс реализовать подобное.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите, чтобы один процесс залез в память другого?

Comment: @Андрей, Ну, наверное да. Через .Net Remoting такое не делается?

Comment: Любой управляемый объект нельзя. Через отображение файлов на память можно сделать общий для двух процессов массив байт, с которым оба процесса будут работать как со своей памятью.

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, что если передавать параметры через `ref` в WCF, то изменения объекта в клиенте будут распространяться на объект в сервере.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{       
    [OperationContract]
    void SendClass(ref TestData data);
}
```

Скорее всего такое же поведение можно получить и в .Net Remoting.

Comment: Этот ref делает совсем не то, что вы думаете. При вызове объект A сериализуется, в виде байт передается на сервер. На сервере байты десериализуются в новый объект B, сервер меняет его свойства. В конце вызова объект B сериализуется, идет в виде байт обратно на клиент. Там байты десериализуются в *новый* объект Значение той переменной, которая была передана с ref в качестве формального параметра в вызов SendClass, меняется с "адреса A" на "адрес C". Объекты при этом границы процессов не пересекают, и объектов у вас целых три, а в вопросе сказано "взаимодействовать **с одним и тем же объектом**"

Comment: В ремоутинге объект передается "по ссылке", но при этом под ссылкой подразумевается не "адрес в памяти" а именно поведение - обращения к методам объекта рантайм перебрасывает в другой процесс. Т.е. это примерно как "TestService передается по ссылке на клиент - ведь вызов TestService.TestMethod на клиенте вызывает TestService.TestMethod на сервере!". К сожалению, абстрацкия в этом механизме очень сильно течет, что вызывает проблемы с производительностью - т.к. вызовы локальных и удаленных методов неразличимы в коде (это фишка!) - то легко случайно сделать кучу дорогих удаленных вызовов.

Comment: @PashaPash, Спасибо за дополнение. Получается, что в WCF методы объекта будут вызываться на его локальной копии и это действительно не то, что я хотел получить в итоге.

Comment: @PashaPash, Значит, если я хочу обойтись только WCF, то единственный путь это сделать в контракте сервиса методы, которые уже будут вызывать методы объекта?

Comment: да, придется руками вызывать методы. MS ушел от "магического" remoting к более прозрачному WCF, а в последнее время - к легковесному Web API (который еще меньше магии добавляет). так что объекты теперь - это просто локальные объекты, и полноценно расшарить их между процессами нельзя.